# What factors affect the g factor?

Tags: intelligence

Is / are there any scientific studies on factors which affect the general intelligence (g) factor?

I did a Google search, but could not find any academic papers on the topic.

Answer (score 7):

So you're basically asking what are the causes of interpersonal differences in intelligence as typically measured by standardised psychometric tests. This question forms the basis for a large proportion of the literature on intelligence. For example see a journal like *Intelligence*.

For a review you could read  [Intelligence: Knowns and Unknowns](http://www.gifted.uconn.edu/siegle/research/correlation/intelligence.pdf)

A few quick observations include that

- Genetics is a major cause
- Environmental causes are often less well understood
- Head start and related programs designed to increase intelligence typically lead to limited long term gains
- Severe environmental factors will negatively affect intelligence