# What method(s) are available which demonstrably increase a person's g factor, (assuming such are available)?

Tags: intelligence, brain-training

Following up on [this](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/7857/what-factors-affect-the-g-factor) question:

What method(s) are available which demonstrably increase a person's* g factor, (assuming such are available)?

(*if a specific target individual is necessary to respond meaningfully to the question, please substitute "person" with "healthy, heterosexual male of age 35 years".)

Comment: Is this a self-help question?

Comment: it would help clarify a little bit if you summarized the first question in addition to linking it. It's not clear what g-factor is, for example.

Comment: @jona: I don't think so, because it's about improving cognitive function in already-healthy individuals in general. [Self-help questions](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/502/why-was-my-self-help-question-closed-as-off-topic) are more dangerous when about diagnosing/treating this weird thing I have that's been getting worse lately. A positive, general question is less likely to endanger someone's health or generate lawsuits, basically...but there's always room for debate on meta of course.

Comment: @Josh: The [*g* factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G_factor_(psychometrics)) is general intelligence; plenty more info on Wikipedia.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is "brain training" effective?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/4175/is-brain-training-effective)

Comment: @ChristianHummeluhr - I think this question is more specific than the linked one. Vote for 'Leave Open' here